# Work with AWS.CLI and aws.s3 when MFA enabled?

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli, ubuntu-18.04

I have downloaded `aws.s3` R package; installed and configured `AWS cli` on Ubuntu 18.04.
I have MFA enabled, paired with a mobile device, for security reasons.

Please advise how can I connect and work with `AWS cli` and `aws.s3` to work with S3?

I get access denied errors.